# Returning the median from two vectors in r

Tags: r, vector, median

I have a vector containing the minimum and maximum of 3 ranges i.e

```
low<-1,2,3
high<-2,3,4
```

represent the ranges 1-2,2-3,and 3-4

I need to return a third vector containing the midpoint of each range i.e.

```
mid<-1.5,2.5,3.5
```

Any quick way to do this?

Comment: You are mixing median and midpoint in your question. They are not the same thing. From your example it looks like it's the midpoint that you are after and not the median.

Comment: The median and midpoint for a series of only 2 numbers would be the same number though....

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you have a set of only two numbers they are indeed the same value. But I would still not use them interchangeably since they mean different things. This is a special case where they happen to be the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've actually got `low <- c(1, 2, 3)` etc, then:

```
mid <- (low + high)/2
```

Comment: I was still re-reading the question because I felt this answer was a bit too obvious!

Comment: Of course it is! I missed that day in grade school. Thanks! Because I am new at programming I keep thinking things are harder than they actually are...